# Explanation of tensorflow "dataflow graphs"

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Google gave the following dataflow graph as an example without any explanation of the scenario itself (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs).
[image]

I cannot understand the use case of such a graph. Why do we need a Logit Layer on top of ReLu layer? What's the use of Softmax (cannot see any link between the output and other nodes)? What are the meanings of the four parameters (two weights and two biases)? I would like to see a real case which matches with this datagraph.

Comment: I think the idea behind this graph was to create an example which covers a lot of the vocabulary used in TensorFlow. Anything else would be too specific for most users.

Comment: @Smokrow Yes. Agree. But would like to know whether we have some real cases which matches this dataflow graph. I suppose Google choose some classical scenario to explain TensorFlow, right?

Comment: Oh. My bad. This is basically just a Dense (relu layer) layer followed by a Output layer(logits). The Costfunction is cross entropy.   It is a 1 layer neural network for categorization.

Comment: @Smokrow: Thanks for your explanation. I just stepped into this domain. Is it possible to expand your comments to an reply and I will be very glad to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This graph is a dense layer, followed by an softmaxlayer. It is basically a neural network with one hidden layer for classification.